# Android 2.3 Tablet: HDMI using both screens

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tablet, screen, hdmi

I've an android 2.3 tablet. When I connect it to the TV the tablet's screen turns off and I can only see in the TV screen. Is there any way to keep both screens on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, there's no way. Your tablet screen and your TV screen use different resolutions and refresh rates, which is generally too much to handle simultaneously for the graphics chip in your tablet.